# Python - Facebook Graph Api - scheduled_publish_time not working with

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Not able to schedule post using facebook graph Api. Its showing error as "facebook.GraphAPIError: (#100) You cannot specify a scheduled publish time on a published post". Without giving scheduled_publish_time, its working fine. But I need to schedule -

```
def main():
    cfg = {
    "page_id" : "13162497478786",
    "access_token": "EAAB1lk5qSpQBAFpeQkf9SfUbKN5m9SRyi7JMa0g0ojLBpwMoYHUuEPkvQqsdpZCAAczYFZBCZAfUhQ9bM2oZAMUtU6bJINRc6cd8ZADSj2jCA9vf0URh9gr9lYhCnZBWhCXUhAPEQUsy8scxRnXZBCfciKVEQ4sjtIZBPy1cZD"
    }
    api = get_api(cfg)
    scheduled_publish_time = 1507039500
    msg = "Welcome to my page with Python14"
    status = api.put_object(parent_object='me', 
                            connection_name='feed',
                            message=msg,
                            link="https://www.facebook.com",
                            scheduled_publish_time = 1507039500 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `published` field to false too, if you want to schedule posts with the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/common-scenarios/#scheduledposts